# One form submit emitting two POST requests

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, express, ng-file-upload

I have been posting simple data (no files) from my form via the $http service.
Those post requests contain JSON and are handled by my express server.

Now I want to add image uploads to my form.

This requries "multipart/form-data" so I installed ng-file-upload on my front end and formidable on my node server.
Posting files requires an ng-file-upload specific service called "Upload" (not $http)

Now I have to make the following decision:

When submitting my form (wich now contains the inital field data + the uploaded file), should I pack everything in a single POST request via the "Upload" service?

Or should I keep the file Upload POST request separate from my preexisting JSON $http POST request? (thus making 2 posts when I submit my form).

Is making two POST requests on one submit somehow bad?

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering the ignorant OP.

As I read on [the docs](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

There is an example called "Upload with form submit and validations"

I looks suggrested that I should use the Upload service and put my form data as well inside.

It's what I did in my application and it seems like the most logical way to do things.

thanks